# How can I use rectangular collision in conjuction with a tile-based game in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, collision

In this project I've been working on, the Player remains stationary in the center of the screen while the maps moves around based on keyboard input.
-Map is tile-based; all of the tiles I have placed manually into a Movie Clip which is 1280x896 pixels, the script then places each of these tiles into an Array (blockArray). Historically, I have always been fairly successful in passing collision information between the Parent script and the Child script (Movie Clip tile-holder) without much trouble using point collision.

-In more physics-based projects, I've had more success with rectangular collision (getRect, and such). In these cases, however, I've never used it before in conjunction with Tile Holder/Movie Clip approached described above.

The following code runs as part of the MoveBall/Player script, which updates per frame. When I run this in the test window, it always crashes the program - perhaps it can't get out of the "for" Loop?

```
public function moveBall (event:Event)
{
    if (lastTime == 0) lastTime = getTimer();
    var timePassed:int = getTimer() -lastTime;
    lastTime += timePassed;

    var newBallX = _Level.x +ballDX*timePassed; //ballDX = ball direction x
    var newBallY = _Level.x+ballDY*timePassed; //ballDY = ball direction y

    var oldBallRect = new Rectangle(_ball.x-ballRadius, _ball.y-ballRadius, ballRadius*2, ballRadius*2);
    var newBallRect = new Rectangle(newBallX-ballRadius, newBallY-ballRadius, ballRadius*2, ballRadius*2); // These correspond to the actual player, which is stationary and 64x64 pixels.

    for(var i:int=blockArray.length-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
            var theBlock = blockArray[i];
            var blockRect:Rectangle = getRect(theBlock);
            if (blockRect.intersects (newBallRect))
            {
                  //collision treatment here
            }
    }
}
```

Below is the method I have been using to build the level in the constructor function:

```
public function startGame()
{
         //constructor code
         stage.focus = stage;
        
         if (_Level == null)
         {
                  _Level = new level_obj(); // this Movie Clip, "level_obj",  is where the blocks that are loaded into the blockArray reside.
                  addChild (_Level);
                
                 for (var i:int = _Level.numChildren-1;i>=0;i--) // this "for" Loop loads the blocks from inside the _Level Movieclip into the blockArray
                 {
                           if (_Level.getChildAt(i) is block_obj)
                           {
                                        blockArray.push(_Level.getChildAt(i));
                           }
                 }
}
```

the main problem I've been encountering here is that `getRect(theBlock)` is not getting the `Rectangle` of the specific block that the `Player/Ball` is supposedly colliding with - `blockArray(i)`. According to my traces, the size of the `blockRect` is 1280x896 - the size of the entire Movie Clip that holds all of the blocks in the `blockArray` - rather than just one of the blocks "(i)", which are 64x64.

Curiously, I made a sort of marker Movie Clip that gets added to the `_Level` Movie Clip during the for Loop in the collision/movement script; this Movie Clip always attaches to the registration point of first Block that I placed there, rather than the registration point of the `_Level` Movie Clip, which is in the upper-left corner on (0,0), and is what the `getRect` command seems to be referencing.

So, my question is: is this a lost cause or is there something that I can put in or take out to make this work?

and if I am wasting my time with this approach, then which of these approaches sound the most viable?

1. Use the regular `Array` method (`newArray = [Block, Block, Block, Lavapit, Block, etc.]` - the construction of the level is handled completely in the `Game/Constructor` Class.
2. Go back to point collision; not sure how well this will work for a physics-based project, though.
3. Or is there perhaps an alternate method that I am unaware of?

In any case; much obliged, all! Good night/morning/afternoon/evening.

Comment: This seems more appropriate on [gamedev.SE], although it might be a bit too localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using Box2d.

I wouldn't call it Tile-based game, if you have a ball jumping around. Tile-based imply that the movement of all object is in straight lines and specific locations, like chess.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've done some reading up on SAT (Separation of Axis Theorem) collision over the past couple days and managed to build a collision system from scratch that, while a little crude, works reasonably well, however, I'll definitely check out Box2D for later projects.

Answer (score 0):

Did some research and built a basic collision system from scratch with some inspiration from [SAT](http://rocketmandevelopment.com/tag/separation-axis-theorem/) theoy.